# What did the Romans use to close their letters?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, idiom, word-request, epistula

As anyone who's written a proper letter knows, one begins with a salutation and ends with a valediction (or, in normal English, opens with "hello" and ends with "goodbye"). Right now, I'm interested in the last half -- the closing. What did Romans write?

That is, where we'd write

> Love,
>
> Boy

What would the Romans write at the end of their letters?

Sincerely,
QPaysTaxes

P.S. I'm looking specifically for valedictions to use with a significant other, but other closers will be useful as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have a look at Cicero's letters, many of them do not have any valediction at all. In a pair of letters exchanged between Q. Metellus and Cicero (Cic. *Fam.* 5.1-5.2), the two men simply stop and end the letter without any closing.

However, there were common ways of providing a valediction. One of the most common you can see at the end of Cicero's fifth letter to his friend Atticus: *cura ut valeas*, "take care that you are well." This was a standard valediction not limited to Cicero. It also can be expanded, as you see he goes on to urge Atticus' continued friendship with Cicero and his cousin.

Other times, a simpler *vale* (good-bye) is used instead. In a letter to Gaius Memmius (*Fam*. 13.1), he ends the letter simply with *vale*, but in a letter to his wife and daughter (*Fam*. 14.2), Cicero signs off with *valete, mea desideria, valete*, "good-bye, my loves, good-bye."

It's further interesting to note that Cicero actually ended that letter with the date and place in which it was written. Sometimes you see this at the top, other times at the bottom, though much of the time it's absent.

Another interesting variation on *vale* is *etiam atque etiam vale*, where *etiam atque etiam* "denotes that an action is done uninterruptedly, incessantly; whence it also conveys the idea of intensity." ([Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=etiam&la=la#lexicon))

Among the common people later than Cicero *valere te opto* and *valere te cupio* were adopted, both of which mean something akin to the English "I hope that you take care." Sometimes *bene* was included for strengthening the wish. There is some disagreement, though, about the origin of the phrase, whether its native Latin or borrowed from the Greek; J. N. Adams in his *Bilingualism and the Latin Language* [(p. 79-80) claims](https://books.google.com/books?id=AMc1WQAnRTkC&pg=PA79) the Vindolanda tablets give the nod to Latin.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in whether or not a valediction is native Latin, just that it was used in Rome. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: One of my favorites is *Vive valeque!* (Horace *Satires* II.5.110 — not a letter, but in his Epistle I.6 he uses the similar *Vive, vale!*)

Comment: @fvogel Well, *epistula* literally means letter!

Comment: @cmw I was unclear: I meant that although the Satire isn't a letter, he uses almost the same essentially the same valediction in one of his Epistulae. To what extent these letters-in-verse are comparable to Cicero's letters, I don't know enough about the genre to say.

Comment: is *mea desideria* really to be translated as a bland *my loves*? it seems to me that it means *my coveted ones* (he's currently exiled and expressing his yearning to see them again). It's really a strong word in this context.

Comment: @mus_siluanus For the purposes of instruction StackExchange, you mean? I can't see how that would improve the answer at all.

Comment: @cmw I think it's important because it means that expression was not a *standard formula* used in letters (what OP requested, if I understand well), it was a one-time highly meaningful expression from Cicero and Cicero only. Even if your focus was on "vale", there could be misunderstandings

Answer (score 2):

I know this: Si tu vales bene est, ego valeo. Usually written with 1 letter: SVBEEV or STVBEEV. Which means: If you are healthy (well) is good, I am healthy (fine) and is equivalent to Hello.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This is certainly interesting – do you happen to remember where you learned it?  A source showing that this comes from the period of the Romans would be a great addition to this answer.

Comment: I have read it in book (on paper) many years ago. I think it was for latin sentences - with corresponding translation and explanation. But if you search for the phrase you will find it many times, e.g. https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090804071628AAzGPMY

Comment: That's not a closing, though. That's usually at the very start of a letter.