# Kind sentence or formula to end a letter to a close friend

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, sentence-translation

I want to write a letter to a close friend who studies classical litterature, and I would like to end it with a sentence (or even just a greeting formula) in Latin which would convey a (non-romantic) feeling along the lines of "You are dear to my heart" or something equivalent. It can even come from an existing work.

I do not know any Latin myself, so explanations are very welcome!

Comment: Welcome to the site! This old question might contain what you are looking for: [What did the Romans use to close their letters?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/184/79) How does that compare to what you are after?

Comment: Adding to @JoonasIlmavirta excellent suggestion, let me also point to https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13779/ending-a-letter-in-latin/13781#13781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following in *[A Dictionary of Latin Phrases](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Mt9FAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA287&lpg=PA287&dq=%22haeres%20mihi%20in%20animo%22&source=bl&ots=57Q84wa_fu&sig=ACfU3U3yr1CukH5kVwfvGTHY1hqXd9XukQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUwd252b30AhWtqpUCHXI7ALsQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22haeres%20mihi%20in%20animo%22&f=false)*, by William Robertson:

> *Haeres mihi in animo*
>
> You are dear to my heart

A more literal translation would be "You adhere to my heart," or "You are impressed on my heart."

To address your concerns about whether this might be used in a non-romantic context, I found a very similar expression used in such a context. In fact, the only diference is that this second expression has *in medullis* instead of *in animo*, but they essentially mean the same thing. The phrase *in medullis* literally means "in [my] inner parts", but it can be equally (and more naturally) be translated as "in [my] heart", or in this context, "to my heart."

Anyway, what I found is from the play *Orestes*, by Wolfgang Waldung. Here we have Iphigenia speaking to to her brother, Orestes:

> *Oresti, fratri meo longe dilectissimo, […] haeres mihi tu in medullis.*
>
> Orestes, my most beloved brother, […] you are dear to my heart

So, as you can see, the expression *Haeres mihi in animo*, or alternatively *Haeres mihi in medullis* may be used to express the love between family or friends.

Comment: Nice suggestion. This simple example posits a syntactic puzzle to me. One could say that the dative _mihi_ can be a semantic argument of the verb _haerere_ or a dativus sympatheticus with respect to _animo_. An easy answer could be: it is both at the same time but, _stricto sensu_ (or should I say, syntactically speaking) I don't think this intuitive "at the same time" analysis is really possible. I'd go for the dativus sympatheticus reading first (it's the 1st analysis that comes to my mind here). The other analysis as verbal argument of _haerere_ is not excluded but it is more marked.

Comment: @Mitomino - My guess would be that the dative goes with the verb, but maybe you're right.

Comment: It seems really fitting, but as I searched about it, I wondered if it was meant more for a romantic love ? It is hard to determine this as I do not understand Latin. But thank you very much nonetheless, in any case the dictionary may help!

Comment: @charon25 - I edited my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: @ExpeditoBipes - I guess this was exactly what I was looking for then, thank you!

Comment: @charon25 - You're welcome.

Comment: L&S give this frequency note on the selection frame of the verb _haerere_: "usually constr. with _in_, the simple abl. or absol., less freq. with dat., with _ad, sub, ex_, etc.". Assuming that the internal argument of the verb _haeres_ in your two examples is _in animo_ & _in medullis_, the dative would not occupy the internal argument slot of the verb (already occupied by the prepositional ablative) but rather would be a dativus sympatheticus. So perhaps your intuition that "the dative goes with the verb" is an influence of your native language, where the prep. _to_ is used.

Comment: @Mitomino - OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"Totus tuus" ([I am] all yours) was a popular friendly valediction in the early modern period.